# Where is the EDM tool in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Trial?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

I just installed VS 2013 Ultimate Trial and I noticed there is no EDM option as shown in the following figure.

[image]

Why?

According to [ADO.NET Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/10/17/ef6-rtm-available.aspx), the tool should be available out of the box.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Visual Studio 2013 onwards we will no longer include the extension that enables configuring an "EDM" data source in this way, e.g. if you add an .MDF file to a project you will no longer see the option to create an EF model, and the option of creating an "EDM" data source based on an existing EDMX model as well as the ability to drag and drop to create data-bound controls automatically in WPF application based on those "EDM" data sources are no longer included.

The recommended ways to create an EF model are either creating the classes,manually (Code First) or adding a new "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" using Add New Item.

The recommended way to do data binding against EF models in WPF applications is through use regular object data sources as explained in [this walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx).

Comment: Thank for answering. I have wasted much time doing the not-working procedures explained in [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/59fa87b1-4395-4c4c-855d-aec94756a055/visual-studio-2013-ultimate-missing-adonet-entity-data-model-designer?forum=vssetup).